# Função preenchendo apenas uma linha

Tags: php, jquery, json, array

Criei uma função para que a medida que o usuário digite um número de cliente, seja preenchido o nome fantasia do mesmo, porém como estes dados vem dentro de uma tabela e eu utilizo array para capturar (`fazer insert e update`) nesses dados, todas linhas se preenchem ao invés da única linha que eu digitei, alguém sabe como consertar isso ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

estrutura da tabela

```
<?php for($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++){ //coloquei este valor para testar ?>        
   <tr>                                                   
        <input type="hidden" maxlength="6" name="recnum[]" value="<?php $row['codigo_produto'] ?>">
        <td><input type="text" maxlength="" name="produto_cliente[]" style="border:none; width:100%; background-color: transparent;"></td>
        <td><input type="text" maxlength="" class="cadcli_codigo" name="cadcli_codigo[]" style="border:none; width:100%; background-color: transparent;"></td>
        <td><input type="text" maxlength="" name="nome_fantasia[]" style="border:none; width:100%; background-color: transparent;"></td>
        <td><input type="text" maxlength="" name="emitente_nfe[]" class="emitente_nfe"  style="border:none; width:100%; background-color: transparent;"></td>       
        <td><input type="text" maxlength="" name="peso_bandeija[]" placeholder="0,0000" style="border:none; width:100%; background-color: transparent;"></td>   
   </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

index.php

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".cadcli_codigo").on("change", function(){

                    var $nome_fantasia = $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='nome_fantasia[]']");

                    $.getJSON('function_pro-1.php',{ 
                            cadcli_codigo: $( this ).val()
                    },function( json ){                          
                            $nome_fantasia.val ( json.nome_fantasia );
                    });
            });
    });
```

function_pro-1.php

```
function nome($cadcli_codigo, $conn){

    $result = "SELECT * FROM cadcli WHERE codigo = '$cadcli_codigo' ";

    $resultado = $conn->query($result);

    // DECLARA A VARIAVEL
    $valores = array();

    if($resultado){

        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
        $valores['nome_fantasia'] = $row['nome_fantasia'];

    } else {
        return json_encode(array( 'error' => mysqli_error($conn) ));        
    }

    return json_encode($valores);                
}

if(isset($_GET['cadcli_codigo'])){
    echo nome($_GET['cadcli_codigo'], $conn);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeira coisa, <s>teria</s> tem que mudar o `id="cadcli_codigo"` para `class="cadcli_codigo"`, pois no *loop* `for` está gerando vários elementos com o mesmo `id`, e isso, além de ser fora dos padrões (*um `id` deve ser único em uma página*<sup>1</sup>) está gerando conflito na captura do `onchange`.

Outra coisa é alterar o seletor da linha abaixo:

```
var $nome_fantasia = $("input[name='nome_fantasia[]']");
```

para a linha abaixo, de modo que o `input` a receber o valor seja o mesmo da linha do `input` que foi digitada a informação (no caso, o código do cliente):

```
var $nome_fantasia = $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='nome_fantasia[]']");
```

Com essas alterações, seu código deve funcionar perfeitamente.

> <sup>1</sup> Existem vários "Josés" no mundo, mas cada José tem uma
>   *impressão digital* diferente do outro. É como no HTML: pode haver vários `divs`, `inputs` etc., mas nenhum deles deve ter o mesmo `id` numa mesma página. No caso da `class` é diferente: pode haver vários "Josés" *carecas* no mundo. Como no HTML, pode haver vários elementos com a mesma `class`.

Comment: alterei o código porém não funciona da mesma forma

Comment: @VictorT. Oq não funciona?

Comment: eu vacilei, vou editar o código acima, perceba que está com # invés de . para referenciar cadcli_codigo, desculpa, obrigado pela ajuda vou colocar como a melhor resposta cara e obrigado por compartilhar sua sabedoria também rs

Comment: @VictorT. Obg! Sucesso!